# Regex.Match whole words

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In `C#`, I want to use a regular expression to match any of these words:

```
string keywords = "(shoes|shirt|pants)";
```

I want to find the whole words in the content string.  I thought this `regex` would do that:

```
if (Regex.Match(content, keywords + "\\s+", 
  RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
{
    //matched
}
```

but it returns true for words like `participants`, even though I only want the whole word `pants`.

How do I match only those literal words?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You should add the word delimiter to your regex:

```
\b(shoes|shirt|pants)\b
```

In code:

```
Regex.Match(content, @"\b(shoes|shirt|pants)\b");
```

Comment: How would you do this but ignore case

Comment: add to the end a `, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: Note the parenthesis are optional in this scenario, removing them will simplify the result

Comment: What is the @ for? It appears to mean literal, although I think | is interpreted as an OR operator and not an actual | character. It also appears this won't work unless the @ is there. Is that true?

Comment: @JosephDoggie It means that the backslashes in the string shouldn't be interpreted as an escape character but instead are part of the string.

Comment: See my post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74288960/c-sharp-regex-and-the-operator-which-seems-to-mean-literal   -- I hope this will helps someone.  I think that detangling the C# part, the regex part, and so forth can be rather difficult.  The post seems to have been a magnet for down-votes, but I guess that happens.

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
Regex.Match(content, @"\b" + keywords + @"\b", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

`\b` matches on word boundaries.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

You need a zero-width assertion on either side that the characters before or after the word are not part of the word:

```
(?=(\W|^))(shoes|shirt|pants)(?!(\W|$))
```

As others suggested, I *think* **\b** will work instead of **(?=(\W|^))** and **(?!(\W|$))** even when the word is at the beginning or end of the input string, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your pattern is better than with "\b", because the latter will not take keywords that, for example, end with a comma ("keyword,"), while it would be expected. Also, the correct pattern is: (?<=\W|^)(keyword)(?=\W|$)

Answer (score 3):

put a word boundary on it using the \b metasequence.

Comment: This does provide an answer, albeit not the regex expression.