# Regex expression to match whole word with special characters not working ?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

I was going through this question 
[C#, Regex.Match whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209049/443568)

It says for match whole word use **"\bpattern\b"**
This works fine for match whole word without any special characters since it is meant for word characters only!

I need an expression to match words with special characters also. My code is as follows

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = Regex.Escape("Hi temp% dkfsfdf hi");
        string pattern = Regex.Escape("temp%");
        var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "\\b" + pattern + "\\b" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        int count = matches.Count;
    }
}
```

**But it fails because of %. Do we have any workaround for this?**
There can be other special characters like 'space','(',')', etc

Answer (score 9):

If you have non-word characters then you cannot use `\b`. You can use the following

```
@"(?<=^|\s)" + pattern + @"(?=\s|$)"
```

**Edit**: As Tim mentioned in comments, your regex is failing precisely because `\b` fails to match the boundary between `%` and the white-space next to it because both of them are non-word characters. `\b` matches only the boundary between word character and a non-word character.

See more on word boundaries [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

**Explanation**

```
@"
(?<=        # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      ^           # Assert position at the beginning of the string
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \s          # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
)
temp%       # Match the characters “temp%” literally
(?=         # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \s          # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      $           # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
"
```

Comment: More exactly, if you have non-alphanumeric characters are the start or end of your search word, you can't use `\b` because that anchor matches between an alnum character and a non-alnum character.

Comment: @Yadala - Simply superb ! Its almost there except that it has one problem. Assume string is "Hi this is stackoverflow"  and pattern is "this " , then it says no matches. This happens because of an empty space after the actual string in pattern. How can we handle this ? Ideally speaking it should say one match found !

Comment: @GuruC If you have white-space in your search string, how can it still be whole word search? I just verified this in Notepad++, if I select Whole word search and search for "this " in "Hi this is stackoverflow"..it does not give any matches.

Comment: @Yadala - But I want the behavior that way. Even in notepad++ if you use option regular expression in search, it matches spaces also. You can use something like visual studio to check the behavior which works superb.

Comment: @GuruC Whole words are bound by some character, generally it is white space in the start and the end. **You need to define your whole word boundaries clearly before proceeding.** You cannot select both `Whole Word` and `Regular Expression` options simultaneously in Notepad++ search.

Answer (score 2):

If the pattern can contain characters that are special to Regex, run it through [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) first.

This you did, but do *not* escape the string that you search through - you don't need that.

Comment: True, but not the (only) reason for his problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, "(?<!\w)-\w+", "")
output = Regex.Replace(output, " -"".*?""", "")
```