# Regex expression to match whole word ?

Tags: .net, regex, match

In reference to my question [Regex expression to match whole word with special characters not working ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8256700/443568),

I got an answer which said

```
@"(?<=^|\s)" + pattern + @"(?=\s|$)"
```

This works fine for all cases except 1 case. It fails when there is space in the pattern.

Assume string is "Hi this is stackoverflow" and pattern is "this " , then it says no matches. This happens because of an empty space after the actual string in pattern.

**How can we handle this ? Ideally speaking it should say one match found !**

Comment: Couldn't you simply trim the pattern from the caller layers ? Assuming this is a user input, you may trim the user input before sending it to the service layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S)|(?<=\S|^)(?=\s))this (?:(?<=\S)(?=\s|$)|(?<=\s)(?=\S|$))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2va1t)

This will also work for pattern that starts with a whitespace.

Basically, what I am doing is to define a custom "word" boundary. But it is not true on a `\W=>\w` or a `\w=>\W` change, its true on a `\S=>\s` or a `\s=>\S` change!

**Here is an example in c#:**

```
string str = "Hi this is stackoverflow";
string pattern = Regex.Escape("this");
MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S)|(?<=\S|^)(?=\s))" + pattern + @"(?:(?<=\S)(?=\s|$)|(?<=\s)(?=\S|$))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine("Amount of matches: " + result.Count);
foreach (Match m in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matched: " + result[0]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Update:**

This "Whitespace" boundary can be done more general, so that on each side of the pattern is the same expression, like this

```
(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))
```

In c#:

```
MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))" + pattern + @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: works in almost all cases but fails while matching strings like "c++ c" in "c++ c c#"

Comment: @pratZ, what is failing? For me it is working fine and I can't see a reason, why it should not match something like c++.

Comment: it matches if you match 'c++' but fails if you match 'c++ c' in the text 'c++ c c#'

Comment: @pratZ, that depends on the pattern you use ...... and it is not covered by this question. Here I would consider "c++ c" as two words.

Comment: The answer you have here is very helpful. It works for 'c++', but it doesn't match things like 'c++ '. Its a whole word (with an empty space in the end), and I dont see a point being it not covered in the question. There can surely be cases like this.