# modify regex to allow floating point number

Tags: java, regex

I had in my code, among other patterns, this one to identify integers

```
Pattern patternNumber = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
```

To read input, I've been using*:

```
 String input = "x: 1.6 ..10;";
 String[] meta = a.split("(?:(?<=^|\\s)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S|^)(?=\\s))\\b(?:(?<=\\S)(?=\\s|$)|(?<=\\s)(?=\\S|$))|\\b");
```

*Courtesy of what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267307/regex-expression-to-match-whole-word/8267757#8267757), slightly modified to fit. I don't have a lot of experience with Regex, but that line magically worked for me.

Then I moved on to also include floating point numbers:

```
Pattern patternNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+");
```

But now I can't seem to get it working. For the floating number part, it splits the number, giving me:

```
1  
.  
6
```

And what I want is:

```
1.6
```

I discovered it works if I use solely:

```
 String input = "1.6";
 String[] meta = a.split("\\D\\.\\D");
```

Any idea on how I can make this part work with the rest of the expression on the split method?

Comment: Just to clarify, in your original string `x: 1.6 ..10;`, did you want to get out `1.6` and `10`?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee No, I did not. For the first part, I was fine with having it splitting my input, giving me a "number, a dot and another number". But now I want it to recognize the whole floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `split` is not the best tool for your purpose.

`split` will *split* your input string on your regex. For example, if you do `split` on `1,2,3,apples` with regex `,`, you'll get `1`, `2,` `3`, and `apples`.

Your complicated `split` regex `"(?:(?<=^|\\s)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S|^)(?=\\s))\\b*(?:(?<=\\S)(?=\\s|$)|(?<=\\s)(?=\\S|$))|\\b"` basically tries to split your string on boundaries between words (taking into account things like a word being at the start/end of the string, or starting with a `.` (the `..10`)).

Instead it would be much easier to explicitly look for the numbers themselves! Instead of *splitting* on spaces between numbers, just *explicitly match* numbers.

So you use the regex for numbers/floats `\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+` and print out the matches (rather than splitting) using `myMatcher.group()`.

e.g.:

```
String input = "x: 1.6 ..10;";
myPattern = Pattern.compile('\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+');
myMatcher = Pattern.matcher(input);
while (myMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(myMatcher.group());
    // will print 1.6, .10
}
```

Depending on what you wanted out (e.g. with respect to the `..10`) the regex can be tweaked.

Comment: That hit my floating number problem on the nail. However, I should've mentioned I was using a String array 'cause I care for indexing tokens in the exact order as they appear on the input string, hence why I decided to use 'split'. My bad for not clarifying early, although your answer might just be what I need for another project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on any series of characters outside the range of those used in a floating point number.

```
String input="x: 1.6 ..10";
String[] meta=input.split("[^0-9.-]+");
```

For the above, meta would be assigned { "1.6" , "..10" }

```
String[] example="123, -.456, 78.910 : 11 : -12".split("[^0-9.-]+")
```

This would produce { "123", "-.456", "78.910", "11", "-12" }

Comment: Sorry for taking long to reply. While your answer makes truckload of sense, I'm having trouble on adding it to my original expression. No matter how I try to arrange it, I end up having to put a "\\b", which breaks my floating point number. Any leads on how I accomplish putting your answer together with my expression?

Comment: Sure.  Specify your expression, a test case to apply it toward, and the outcome you want.  You're probably really close.

Comment: The expression, test case and outcome are the ones I posted on the initial post. As weird and silly as it may seem, I'm actually having trouble adding your `[^0-9.-]+` into the expression described in the opening question. For example, `x: 1.6 ..10;` should give me a split string containing: `x`, `:`, `1.6`, ` `, `..`, `10`, and `;`. It works for everything except the `1.6`, which it continues to break into `1`, `.` and `6` if add your answer to that one bigger expression. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I see.  You're not just trying to extract floating point numbers, you're wanting to preserve their context in the original string, perhaps even doing some parsing of other words and symbols at the same time.

Comment: Given the complexity of your request, I think you should consider "rolling your own".  You can .toCharArray() your String and step through it, character by character, deciding when you've reached a word boundary and appending that word to an ArrayList, tossing out anything interpreted to be a separator.  What you're trying to do doesn't seem weird or silly... it just happens to be more complex than just picking out numbers from a string.