# Regular expression to match every word starting with another word (including special characters)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using a simple regular expression to match strings which containing words starting with:

```
string regExp = @"\b" + searchFor; // searchFor is input value to look for
matchName = Regex.IsMatch(recipient.User.FullName, regExp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It works great for words (of course), but if FullName contain something like:

```
This is Ex$ample
```

And user try to looks for `Ex$a`, then it never matches.

Or if user searchFor is:

```
$
```

It returns true all the time for the records.

I tried to look in other posts but I can't find something similar.

Thanks

```
**UPDATED**
```

Let me try to explain. The idea is to look for names that begin with certain words:

```
string searchFor = "Gha";
```

and recipient.User.FullName list contain:

```
Jordan Ghassari
James Cunningham
Ghabriel Bercholee
```

The matches must be:

```
Jordan Ghassari 
Ghabriel Bercholee
```

It is also necessary to consider that fullname list can contain special characters. It needed to include special characters in the search

Search for `o^bri` 
and obtain:

```
O^Brian
```

Search for `#34` 
and obtain:

```
Depto #345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain of your full question, but you'll need to use a [Regex escaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) for conditions like this one. The `$` is a special character. It would be `\$` to actually search for a dollar sign. You should look up other special characters and be aware of them too, though C# regex escaper will do the tick.

**EDIT** Like this:

```
string[] names = 
{
    "Jordan Ghassari",
    "James Cunningham",
    "Ghabriel Bercholee",
    "O^Brian",
    "Depto #345",
    "This is Ex$ample",
    "$amuel"
};

string searchFor = Console.ReadLine(); // Input
searchFor = @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))" + Regex.Escape(searchFor); // searchFor is input value to look for

Regex regEx = new Regex(searchFor, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

List<string> matchedNames = new List<string>();
foreach(string name in names){
    if (regEx.IsMatch(name))
    {
        matchedNames.Add(name);
    }
}

foreach (string match in matchedNames) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

**[This is a tested and working solution.](http://ideone.com/Vxb7IN)** You just escape the portion of the pattern that the user inputs and then use the pattern to create a new Regex object. The `\b` can't be used to match special charecters so we use some C# lookbehinds as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267307/regex-expression-to-match-whole-word/8267757#8267757).  Then you loop though each of your strings and store the matches in some kind of data structure, I chose a generic list.

Comment: So your suggestion is do Regex.Escape(searchFor) and Regex.Escape(recipient.User.FullName) ?

Comment: Thanks @colepanike, do you know why if there is name like "$amuel" and searchFor = "$am" it never match?

Comment: It's the nature of `\b` it only matches word characters, special chars are not part of that list. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler to do this without RegEx:

```
string searchString = "This is Ex$ample";
string searchFor = "Ex$a";

searchString = " " + searchString;
searchFor = " " + searchFor;

if (searchString.IndexOf(searchFor) >= 0)
{
    // Match
} else {
    // No Match
}
```

If you want a case insensitive search, use this instead:

```
if (searchString.IndexOf(searchFor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
    // Match
} else {
    // No Match
}
```

Comment: IndexOf doesn't work because it look in any place in the searchString. I need look starting a word with searchFor.

Comment: @ARR01 - Look at my updated answer, which will search the beginning of words only.

Comment: Thanks @Icemanind. Your solution is correct and another way to resolve it.