# Conditional Regex Replace

Tags: regex

Consider the following regex rule for text replacement

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/'.$myitem.'[ab]/', "", $mystring);
```

This will replace  `$myitem` with a blank character in `$mystring` if and only if it is followed by either `a` or `b`.

My requirement is not to replace it with a blank character but to replace it with:

`a` if `a` is encountered or  `b` if `b` is encountered.

I cannot do it in two iterations like:

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/'.$myitem.'a/', "a", $mystring);
$mystring = preg_replace('/'.$myitem.'b/', "b", $mystring);
```

because the first iteration will also have some side effects on `$mystring` making the second rule useless in that case.

Is there a way to do this conditional replacement in a single iteration ?

**edited in response to answers**

OK I had oversimplified my question but here is the actual regex rule

```
'(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))'.$myitem.'(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$)) *([ab])'
```

Now in this situation how do I count the backreference number as I see some conditional groupings as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture and use backrefence in replacement:

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/'.$myitem.'([ab])/', '$1', $mystring);
```

Comment: thanks but I had oversimplified my regex rule. I have now edited my question  to include the actual regex. Can you tell how do i count the backreference number in this case ?

Comment: this regex is for whole word replacements  when words may also contain special characters and hence simple word boundaries may  not work. I borrowed this rule from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267307/regex-expression-to-match-whole-word/8267757#8267757

Comment: See before EDIT question you had sample input/output. Without that it is difficult to understand the requirements. IMO it is also not fair to change the question after getting answers. If question was oversimplified then you could ask a new question also.

Comment: I have already given you the credits for answering. No issues. Thanks

Comment: Thanks and please don't get me wrong. I would still try to answer your new question as I like to work on challenging regex problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture and replace:

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/'.$myitem.'([ab])/', "\1", $mystring);
```

Comment: thanks but I had oversimplified my regex rule. I have now edited my question  to include the actual regex. Can you tell how do i count the backreference number in this case ?