# How to match complete word to complete word seperated by space

Tags: c#

I want to perform a search operation on a string. for e.g I have a following string

**Hi My name is Babar and I am a .Net developer**

Now if I want to search that if any word is present in this string or not using following code.

```
if(str.Contains("am"))
{
return true;
}
```

There is problem in this method it will return 2 word are matched **am** and **name**. The result is **am** is correct but I want that the result should be a complete word separated by space. It should not return **name** as result. It should match the complete word not part of it. kindly help me in this problem

Comment: split it by space then search by name ?

Comment: Quick thought about this, you can use `str.Contains(" am ")`. Or split string to array, ...

Comment: This regex `\bam\b` will match the word `am` using word boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution are Regular Expressions.

Look here:
[C#, Regex.Match whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/c-regex-match-whole-words)

Regular expressions are more efficient and more versatile.
Of course, sometimes those would be a cannon for a sparrow and it is better to use Contains() or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
string str = "Hi My name is Babar and I am a.Net developer";

        foreach (string s in str.Split(' ').ToArray())
        {
            if (s.Equals("am"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use regex with the `IsMatch` method:

```
Regex.IsMatch("Hi My name is Babar and I am a .Net developer", @"\b(am)\b")
```

Will return `True` if the string has a match.

Each `\b` indicates a blank space.

Comment: This answer is correct. `\b` however does not match "a blank space", it matches a word boundary, which is a zero width match.