# How to pass values from a string array into a Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently writing a program that will check a line from a file and see if a US state is contained in that line and that it is also spelled correctly. I have it currently working for a single state. I would like to be able to see if any of all the US states are in the line.

This is my code so far below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var r = new Regex(@"\bArizona\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\sampledata.dat");
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            var m = r.Match(s);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // false
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Essentially I would like to do something like
`var r = new Regex(@"\bAll US States.txt\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: You can try loading all of the states from your file into an array or list and loop through each one as a new regex and do your check.

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/c-regex-match-whole-words

Comment: @ephtee Running 50 regular expressions instead of one seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @juharr No doubt. But given the nature of the question this seems like it's probably a homework assignment and therefore an acceptable approach which will teach him/her to consider better ways to do it.

Comment: Hi guys, trying to write this program to automate a process in work. At the moment someone has to manually check the file to make sure all states are spelled correctly. There can be up to 1000 lines in each file.

Comment: So, how about write a code to verify all of these files and fix it?

Comment: @AndrewPaes Thats what I'm trying to do at the moment, ideally I'd like to have the program fix it automatically but for now I'm just going to get it to notify me when there is an error. I haven't programmed in a while so every small step is a challenge!

Comment: I see. Nice to have you back. So I think you could use Lucene.Net to find these  wrong words. After this you can right another code to open document and fix them. Lucene can find words by similarity using Regex also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is

```
\b(?:Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|...)\b
```

To compose it from a list stored in an `All US States.txt` file use `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
var states = File.ReadAllLines(@"All US States.txt");
var r = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b(?:{0})\b", string.Join("|", states)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This worked for me, however what does the `?` in `(@"\b(?:{0})\b"` do?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. This allows to ensure that word boundaries (`\b`) are applied to _any_ state from the alternation list.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I like the solution, but `(?:...)` is equivalent to plain parenthesis `( )`, the only difference that it does not store the matched value for later reference.  It does not change the matching behavior of the parenthesis, so `?:` is not required to have `\b` applied correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to see if any of the states were contained, you could essentially use the [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) method to generate an expression that would match any of them:

```
// Read your lines
var states = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\states.txt");

// Build a pipe delimited string (e.g. State1|State2|State3 ...) to use an a Regex with necessary boundaries
// leading and trailing boundaries
var pattern = $@"\b{(string.Join("\b|\b", states))}\b";

// Now use that pattern to build a Regex to check against (using C# string interpolation)
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Now loop through your data here and check each line
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\sampledata.dat");
foreach (string s in lines)
{
        var m = regex.Match(s);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // false
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Additionally, if you aren't able to use string interpolation to build your pattern, simply use the older [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) approach:

```
var pattern = string.Format("\b{0}\b", string.Join("\b|\b", states));
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `\b` on each end.

Comment: This pattern would match `New Yorker`, which is not what OP would expect, I believe.