# Split a paragraph to separate one or two digit numbers with PowerShell

Tags: html, regex, powershell, cpu-word

I'm attempting to parse and format some text from an HTML file into Word. I'm doing this by capturing each paragraph into an array and then writing it into the word document one paragraph at a time. However, there are superscripted references sprinkled throughout the text. I'm looking for a way to superscript these references in the new Word file and thought I would use regex and split to make this work. Here is an example paragraph:

```
$p = "This is an example sentence.1 The number is a reference note that should be superscripted and can be one or two digits long."
```

Here is the code I tried to split and select the digit(s):

```
[regex]::Split($p,"(\d{1,2})")
```

This works for single and double digits. However, if there are more than two digits, it still splits it, but moves the extra numbers to the next line. Like so:

```
This is an example sentence.
10

0
The number is a reference note that should be superscripted and can be one or two digits long.
```

This is important because there are sometimes larger numbers (3-10 digits) in the text that I don't want to split on. My goal is to take a block of text with reference note numbers and seperate out the notes so I can perform formatting functions on them when I write it out to the Word file. Something like this (untested):

```
$paragraphs | % {
    $a = @([regex]::Split($_,"(\d{1,2})"))
    $a | % {
        $text = $_
        if ($text -match "(\d{1,2})")
        {
            $objSelection.Font.SuperScript = 1
            $objSelection.TypeText("$text")
            $objSelection.Font.SuperScript = 0
        }
        Else
        {
            $objSelection.Style="Normal"
            $objSelection.TypeText("$text")
        }

    }
        $text = "`v"
        $objSelection.TypeText("$text")
        $objSelection.TypeParagraph()
}
```

**EDIT:**
The following regex expression works when I test it with the above loop in it's own script:

```
"(?<![\d\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)"
```

However, when I run it in the parent script, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Split" and the argument count: "2"
$a = [regex]::Split($_,"(?<![\d\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)")
```

How would I go about troubleshooting this error?

Comment: Maybe you need to only match 1+ digits after a `.`? Try `[regex]::Split($p,"(?<=\.\s*)(\d+)\s*")`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew: That pattern creates a positive match for 1,2 & 3 digit numbers. How can I use that to not split when there are 3+ digit numbers in the string?

Comment: That did the opposite. It split the 3+ digit number, but did not split on 1 or 2.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I am in a rush. You want `"(?<=\.\s*)(\d{1,2})(?!\d)\s*"`, or even `"(?<=\.\s*)(\d{1,2})\b\s*`. If `"\b(\d{1,2})\b"` also works, I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/regex-match-whole-words).

Comment: The first one works! I will now test it in my code to see if I can format the split string.

Comment: The last one did not work as it duplicated the matched digits in the output.

Comment: Try [`"(?<![\d\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)\s*"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cd%5cs%5d%29%28%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%28%3f!%5cd%29%5cs*&i=This+is+an+example+sentence.1+The+number2Number++2+number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[regex]::Split($p,"(?<![\d\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)\s*")
```

It only matches and captures one or two digits that are neither followed nor preceded with another digit, and not preceded with any whitespace char. Any trailing whitespace is matched with `\s*` and is thus removed from the items that are added into the resulting array.

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cd%5cs%5d%29%28%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%28%3f!%5cd%29%5cs*&i=This+is+an+example+sentence.1+The+number+is+a+reference+note+that+should+be+superscripted+and+can+be+one+or+two+digits+long.):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<![\d\s])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current position, there is a digit or a whitespace
- `(\d{1,2})` - Group 1: one or two digits
- `(?!\d)` - that cannot be followed with another digit (it is a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern matches immediately to the right of the current location)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: I'm on a mobile now, I'll add a  demo after I'm back to my PC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested it on a few more data sets and it looks like you have a positive lookbehind to match on a "." character. Not all reference numbers are after a period. Is there a way to modify so that it doesn't require that? Also, when using this regex in a "match", it doesn't seem to work properly. I'll update the question to reflect what I mean.

Comment: @McKenning See update. Do not use `"\s*(?<!\d)(\d{1,2})(?!\d)\s*"` in a matching method, it is not meant to be used there. If you need the leading/trailing whitespace, remove `\s*` subpatterns.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I modified the edit to request excluding matches with a preceding space. I tried using the Regex demo tool but just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @McKenning Try [`"(?<![\d\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)\s*"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cd%5cs%5d%29%28%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%29%28%3f!%5cd%29%5cs*&i=This+is+an+example+sentence.1+The+number2Number++2+number)

Comment: That worked for a standalone script, but I got an error when I ran it from the main script. I've updated the question with more detail and marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @McKenning Sorry,  I could not repro. Perhaps, there is an issue before that line, `$_` is something not expected (you know, regex only works with strings), etc.