# How to replace group of words in file

Tags: c#, regex

I have following lines in my file

> set ABCHOST=XOQA
>
> set ABCDB=qa
>
> set ABCDBFORLOGGINGSTATUS=%ABCDB%
>
> set ABCDB_LOGICAL_LOGFILENAME=%ABCDB%_log
>
> set ABCDB_UID_ENCRYPTED=dummy
>
> set ABCDB_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED=dummy

I am reading the value of ABCHOST, ABCDB, ABCDBFORLOGGINGSTATUS, ABCDB_LOGICAL_LOGFILENAME and so on.. from excel sheet and want to replace value in this file.

For example if ABCHOST value in excel is XOSTAGING than I want to replace it like below

> set ABCHOST=XOSTAGING

Similar way others as well.

I am currently doing as below

```
string pattern = @".*" + variableName + ".*";
var result = Regex.Replace(stateParamFile, pattern, "set " + variableName + "=" + variableValue);
```

Basically above regular expression is replacing ABCDB with everywhere even this word is not fully matched, I have tried to search online but unable to get the detail of solution.

But I am getting following output which is wrong

> set ABCHOST=.
>
> set ABCDB=Msbuild
>
> set ABCDB=Msbuild
>
> set ABCDB=Msbuild
>
> set ABCDB=Msbuild
>
> set ABCDB=Msbuild

My expectation is

> set ABCHOST=.
>
> set ABCDB=MSBuild
>
> set ABCDBFORLOGGINGSTATUS=MyValue1
>
> set ABCDB_LOGICAL_LOGFILENAME=MyValue2
>
> set ABCDB_UID_ENCRYPTED=MyValue3
>
> set ABCDB_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED=MyValue4

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: As is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209081/3832970), you need to build the regex like `@"\b" + word + @"\b"`. Or, `$@"\b{Regex.Escape(word)}\b"`