# Regex to find after particular word inside a string

Tags: regex

I am using regex to find few keywords after colon(:) and the best I have reached so far is:

**sample test case**

```
test {
    test1 {
        sadffd(test: "aff", aaa: "aa1") {}
    }
}
```

Now I have to find a keyword inside `()` brackets and its working for 'aaa' but when I add `test` it fails, it matches entire words in string.

my regex so far

**`\btest(.*\w")`** (failed case) expected `"aff"` returned `"aff", aaa: "aa1"`

**`\baaa(.*\w")`**  (pass case) returned `"aa1"`

please let me know if more information is needed

Comment: _Don't_ use regex to parse JSON.  Use a JSON parser instead.  Most major programming languages have very good JSON support.

Comment: it looks like json, but is not. and update: it returns remaining string, which is failing test case. @TimBiegeleisen thanks :)

Comment: you can use Regex.Match. as https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209058/1656581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
:\s*"(.*?)"
```

And the data you need is in the first capturing group.

Explanation

```
:\s*"(.*?)"
:               colon
 \s*            followed by optionally any number of spaces
    "           followed by quote
     (   )      capturing group, containing...
      .*?           any number of character, matching as few as possible
          "     followed by quote
```

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/WnvzdG/1

---

Update:
If you want to match ONLY after specific keywords, followed by colon, you can do something like:

```
(KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|KEYWORD3)\s*:\s*"(.*?)"
```

First capture group will be the keyword matched, second capture group will be the value.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach (executed in Python)

```
items = ['test{test1 {sadffd(test: "aff", aaa: "aa1") {}}}']
for item in items:
    print(re.findall(r'"(\w+)"',item))
    print(re.findall(r'(?<=: )"(\w+)"',item))
```

**Output**

```
['aff', 'aa1']
['aff', 'aa1']
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but, is there any way we can solve this using regex only, language independent

Answer (score 1):

I believe a simple regex would work to get everything inside the double quotes in your case:

```
("\w+")
```

Note that your question above says you want to capture `"aff"` and not just `aff` so I've included the surrounding quotes within the capturing group.

Example from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Wu1AHd/1):

[image]

It's pretty crude but this should be OK for the input you've presented. (It wouldn't handle things like an escaped double quote in the string, for example).

Comment: But I needed a particular word next to mentioned. Anyway @adrin answer solves the purpose. thanks :)

Comment: @emotionlessbananas slightly updated my answer (though accepted already) to include handling of "particular word"