# Regex match an entire number with lookbehind and look ahead logic(without word boundaries)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am trying to detect if a string has a number based on few conditions. For example I don't want to match the number if it's surrounded by parentheses and I'm using the lookahead and lookbehind to do this but I'm running into issues when the number contains multiple digits.  Also, the number can be between text without any space separators.

My regex:

(?https://regex101.com/r/RnTSMJ/1

Sample examples:
{2}: Should NOT Match. //My regex Works

{34: Should NOT Match. //My regex matches 4 in {34

45}: Should NOT Match. //My regex matches 4 in {45

{123}: Should NOT Match. //My regex matches 2 in {123}

I looked at [Regex.Match whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/regex-match-whole-words) but this approach doesn't work for me.  If I use word boundaries, the above cases work as expected but then cases like the below don't where numbers are surrounded with text.  I also want to add some additional logic like don't match specific strings like 1st, 2nd, etc or #1, #2, etc

updated regex:

```
(?<!\[|\{|\(|#)(\b\d+\b)(?!\]|\}|\|st|nd|rd|th)
```

See here https://regex101.com/r/DhE3K4/4

123abd //should match 123

abc345 //should match 234

ab2123cd // should match 2123

Is this possible with pure regex or do I need something more comprehensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match 1 or more digits asserting what is on the left and right is not `{`, `}` or a digit or any of the other options to the right

```
(?<![{\d#])\d+(?![\d}]|st|nd|rd|th)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![{\d#])` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `{`, `#` or a digit
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `[\d}]|st|nd|rd|th` Match a digit, `}` or any of the alternatives
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tkzavo/1)

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I'm still curious, how does this work without hitting the same issue when you have a lot of consecutive numbers like in my example above: {123}.  2 matches after the look ahead/behind ruled out 1 and 3.  I would expect if I had more digits like 11233 then the same issue would arise, the look ahead/behind would exclude 11, and 33 but then still match 2

Comment: Taking your pattern from the first link, shortened to `(?<![[{()])(\d+)(?![\]})])` https://regex101.com/r/DnYkwM/1 and this string `{112333}`, the pattern first asserts that what is on the left is not any of the chars `[` `{` `(` or `)` That assertion if true after the first 1. Then it will match 1+ digits in a greedy way and wants to fulfill the last assertion, which is on the right is not any of the chars in the last character class. Because the `\d+` uses a quantifier, it has steps to backtrack. The last digit in the match does not fulfill the assertion, but then backtracking 1 step does.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex is giving the expected result.

```
(?<![#\d{])\d+(?!\w*(?:}|(?:st|th|rd|nd)\b))
```

[Regex Link](https://regex101.com/r/M03axL/1)