# Regex that matches any words, but not something like a single character after a digit

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex and I need to extract words from a string, without extracting a single character after a digit.

Example string

```
"some great string with a £4.8m in the middle"
```

Desired output

```
"some", "great", "string", "with", "a", "in", "the", "middle"
```

To do this I attempted using this particular regular expression:

```
[^\W_0-9]+(?:['_-][^\W_]+)*
```

However this does not entirely work, as it also matches the letter `m` after `£4.8m`.
Any suggestions on how I could solve this?

Comment: I'd tend to make my regex match both and have the code filter it out.  Use a hammer to do the hammer work and a wrench to do the wrench work

Comment: `\b[^\W\d]+\b` could work for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex.Match whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/regex-match-whole-words)

Comment: @RyszardCzech No, that doesn't answer the question at all.  OP isn't trying to match against a list of predefined words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

[Example](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Thank you! This works for the most part with one exception -  now something like `"john's place"` matches `"john", "s", "place"`. Any way to discard the `s`?

Comment: `\b[a-zA-Z\']+\b` will match `john's` as one match.